# How to organize layout using PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, widget, pyqt5

I'm very new to PyQt and I'm finding ordering the widgets in the window pretty hard.

I have a plot that updates in real-time, a table that updates every time that the user clicks on the plot, and two buttons (start/stop).

The current layout is behaving this way:

[image]

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Where "other widgets" correspond to future Widgets I'll add when this is working (such as a slider or a dropdown list). The table should also be as thin as possible, to maximize the size of the plot and don't have the table occupying unnecessary space. My current code is the following one (it's self-contained):

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def onclick(event):
    global clicks
    clicks.append(event.xdata)
    return

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self._title = 'Prueba real-time'
        self.setWindowTitle(self._title)
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self._main)

        dynamic_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(10, 10)))
        layout.addWidget(dynamic_canvas)

        self._dynamic_ax = dynamic_canvas.figure.subplots()
        dynamic_canvas.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
        self._dynamic_ax.grid()
        self._timer = dynamic_canvas.new_timer(
            100, [(self._update_window, (), {})])
        self._timer.start()

        button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop', self)
        layout.addWidget(button_stop)
        button_stop.clicked.connect(self.button_pressed)

        button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start', self)
        layout.addWidget(button_start)
        button_start.clicked.connect(self.button_pressed)

        self.table_clicks = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table_clicks.setRowCount(0)
        self.table_clicks.setColumnCount(2)
        layout.addWidget(self.table_clicks)

    def button_pressed(self):
        if self.sender().text() == 'Stop':
            self._timer.stop()
        if self.sender().text() == 'Start':
            self._timer.start()

    def _update_window(self):
        self._dynamic_ax.clear()
        global x, y1, y2, y3, N, count_iter, last_number_clicks
        x.append(x[count_iter] + 0.01)
        y1.append(np.random.random())
        idx_inf = max([count_iter-N, 0])
        if last_number_clicks < len(clicks):
            for new_click in clicks[last_number_clicks:(len(clicks))]:
                rowPosition = self.table_clicks.rowCount()
                self.table_clicks.insertRow(rowPosition)
                self.table_clicks.setItem(rowPosition,0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(new_click)))
                self.table_clicks.setItem(rowPosition,1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Descripcion"))
            last_number_clicks = len(clicks)
        self._dynamic_ax.plot(x[idx_inf:count_iter], y1[idx_inf:count_iter],'-o', color='b')
        count_iter += 1
        self._dynamic_ax.figure.canvas.draw()
#%%
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pressed_key = {}
    clicks = []
    last_number_clicks = len(clicks)
    N = 25
    y1 = [np.random.random()]
    x = [0]
    count_iter = 0
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The structure that you want is a grid so you should use a `QGridLayout`.

QGridLayout has the addWidget() method where you can indicate the row and column where the widget will be placed, the same with addLayout()

> void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget *widget, int row, int column, Qt::Alignment alignment = ...)
>
> void QGridLayout::addLayout(QLayout *layout, int row, int column, Qt::Alignment alignment = ...)

In your case the structure should be the following:

```
QGridLayout
├── Plot (0, 0)
├── Table (0, 1)
├── Other Widgets (1, 0)
└── QVBoxLayout (1, 1)
    ├── button_start
    └── button_stop
```

Then you can indicate the weight of each column, that is, say that the column width will have a proportional width with respect to column 2 using `setColumnStretch()`:

```
layout.setColumnStretch(0, 2)
layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
```

Considering the above we have the following:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def onclick(event):
    global clicks
    clicks.append(event.xdata)

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self._title = 'Prueba real-time'
        self.setWindowTitle(self._title)

        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        
        dynamic_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(10, 10)))
        self._dynamic_ax = dynamic_canvas.figure.subplots()
        dynamic_canvas.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
        self._dynamic_ax.grid()
        self._timer = dynamic_canvas.new_timer(
            100, [(self._update_window, (), {})])
        self._timer.start()

        button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop', self)
        
        button_stop.clicked.connect(self._timer.stop)

        button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start', self)
        
        button_start.clicked.connect(self._timer.start)

        self.table_clicks = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.table_clicks.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        other_widget = QtWidgets.QLabel("Other widgets", 
            font=QtGui.QFont("Times", 60, QtGui.QFont.Bold), 
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        # layouts

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self._main)

        layout.addWidget(dynamic_canvas, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.table_clicks, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(other_widget, 1, 0)

        button_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addWidget(button_stop)
        button_layout.addWidget(button_start)        

        layout.addLayout(button_layout, 1, 1)

        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 2)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)

    def _update_window(self):
        self._dynamic_ax.clear()
        global x, y1, y2, y3, N, count_iter, last_number_clicks
        x.append(x[count_iter] + 0.01)
        y1.append(np.random.random())
        idx_inf = max([count_iter-N, 0])
        if last_number_clicks < len(clicks):
            for new_click in clicks[last_number_clicks:(len(clicks))]:
                rowPosition = self.table_clicks.rowCount()
                self.table_clicks.insertRow(rowPosition)
                self.table_clicks.setItem(rowPosition,0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(new_click)))
                self.table_clicks.setItem(rowPosition,1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Descripcion"))
            last_number_clicks = len(clicks)
        self._dynamic_ax.plot(x[idx_inf:count_iter], y1[idx_inf:count_iter],'-o', color='b')
        count_iter += 1
        self._dynamic_ax.figure.canvas.draw()
#%%
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pressed_key = {}
    clicks = []
    last_number_clicks = len(clicks)
    N = 25
    y1 = [np.random.random()]
    x = [0]
    count_iter = 0
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would personally separate the different parts of the program in their own class and use several vertical and horizontal layouts to position the widgets. This especially helps if you want to add features. Especially for large applications this helps to keep the MainWindow, which always tends to become a mess, to be more simple and easier to understand

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def onclick(event):
    global clicks
    clicks.append(event.xdata)
    return

class TableWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.table_clicks = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table_clicks.setRowCount(0)
        self.table_clicks.setColumnCount(2)
        layout.addWidget(self.table_clicks)

        button_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(button_widget)
        button_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(button_widget)

        button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop', self)
        button_layout.addWidget(button_stop)
        button_stop.clicked.connect(self.parent.plot_widget.button_pressed)

        button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start', self)
        button_layout.addWidget(button_start)
        button_start.clicked.connect(self.parent.plot_widget.button_pressed)

class PlotWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,*args,**kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        dynamic_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(10, 10)))
        layout.addWidget(dynamic_canvas)

        self._dynamic_ax = dynamic_canvas.figure.subplots()
        dynamic_canvas.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
        self._dynamic_ax.grid()
        self._timer = dynamic_canvas.new_timer(
            100, [(self._update_window, (), {})])
        self._timer.start()


    def button_pressed(self):
        if self.sender().text() == 'Stop':
            self._timer.stop()
        if self.sender().text() == 'Start':
            self._timer.start()

    def _update_window(self):
        self._dynamic_ax.clear()
        global x, y1, y2, y3, N, count_iter, last_number_clicks
        x.append(x[count_iter] + 0.01)
        y1.append(np.random.random())
        idx_inf = max([count_iter-N, 0])
        if last_number_clicks < len(clicks):
            for new_click in clicks[last_number_clicks:(len(clicks))]:
                rowPosition = self.parent.table_widget.table_clicks.rowCount()
                self.parent.table_widget.table_clicks.insertRow(rowPosition)
                self.parent.table_widget.table_clicks.setItem(rowPosition,0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(new_click)))
                self.parent.table_widget.table_clicks.setItem(rowPosition,1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Descripcion"))
            last_number_clicks = len(clicks)
        self._dynamic_ax.plot(x[idx_inf:count_iter], y1[idx_inf:count_iter],'-o', color='b')
        count_iter += 1
        self._dynamic_ax.figure.canvas.draw()


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self._title = 'Prueba real-time'
        self.setWindowTitle(self._title)
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self._main)

        self.plot_widget = PlotWidget(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.plot_widget)


        self.table_widget = TableWidget(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)


#%%
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pressed_key = {}
    clicks = []
    last_number_clicks = len(clicks)
    N = 25
    y1 = [np.random.random()]
    x = [0]
    count_iter = 0
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```